# How do I update the live preview of MarkdownDeep when adding text from jQuery .val()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, markdown, markdowndeep

I'm currently evaluating MarkdownDeep for use on my website.  Above the editor I display a list of images the user previously uploaded.  To insert the image (which is wrapped in a link to the larger version) into the `<textarea>`, the user clicks the image.  However, the live preview doesn't show the image until the user adds additional input in the `<textarea>`.  Is it possible to update the live preview through jQuery?

Here's the code I'm using to insert the image:

```
$("img").click(function () {
    var imgsrc = $(this).attr('src');
    var content = $('textarea').val();
    $('textarea').val(content + '<a href="' + imgsrc + '"><img src="' + imgsrc + '" width="50" height="50" /></a>');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. If we bind the `focus` event in the MarkdownDeepEditor.js file, then set the focus to the `textarea`, the preview will update.

Add the following after line 539 in *MarkdownDeepEditor.js:* (you should see the other BindEvents.)

```
BindEvent(textarea, "focus", function(){ed.onMarkdownChanged();});
```

In my html, I'll add the following code:

```
$("img").click(function () {
    var imgsrc = $(this).attr('src');
    var content = $('textarea').val();
    $('textarea').val(content + '<a href="' + imgsrc + '"><img src="' + imgsrc + '" width="50" height="50" /></a>');
    $('textarea.mdd_editor').focus();
});
```